# Is it possible bind variables by name AND position in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, python-oracledb

When executing an Oracle SQL query from an application using a driver like [python-oracledb](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), it is possible to bind variables by name or by position. Binding variables by name uses named arguments, and binding variables by position uses arguments given as lists or tuples.

By name:

```py
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT 'Var values are ' || :var || ' and ' || :var AS var_value
    FROM dual
''', var="something")
```

The value of `var_value` will be `'Var values are something and something'`.

By position:

```py
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT 'Var values are ' || :var || ' and ' || :var AS var_value
    FROM dual
''', ["one thing", "another thing"])
```

Now the value of `var_value` will be `'Var values are one thing and another thing'`.

Is it possible to do both? e.g.,

```py
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT 'Var values are ' || :name_var || ', ' || :pos_var || ', and ' || :pos_var AS var_value
    FROM dual
''', ["another thing", "something else"], name_var="one thing")
```

I checked [the documentation](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-by-name-or-position), but no example is given of binding by both name and position.

Comment: I don't think you can combine both, but the best is try and see if it works.

Comment: In python, positional arguments come before keyword arguments so if it was going to work you would use: `cursor.execute(query_string, ["var1", "var2"], a="varA", b="varB")`. Why don't you try it and find out (and if it works you can self-answer the question)?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my original post and swapped the keyword and positional arguments.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to bind both by position and by name. If you try that you will get this error: `DPY-2006: positional and named binds cannot be intermixed` or `DPY-2005: expecting positional arguments or keyword arguments, not both`, depending on which approach you take.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and received this error message: "oracledb.exceptions.ProgrammingError: DPY-2005: expecting positional arguments or keyword arguments, not both".

In my particular case, I need to reference the keyword argument once before and after the positional arguments. I tested this primitive workaround, and it works:

```py
name_var = "one thing"
pos_vars = ["another thing", "something else"]
cursor.execute('''
    SELECT
        :name_var AS first_name_ref,
        :pos_var || ' and ' || :pos_var AS pos_refs,
        :name_var AS second_name_ref
    FROM dual
''', [name_var, *pos_vars, name_var])
```